# Can't delete few files from google drive

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api

[image]

please help me. I am unable to delete these files from my google drive offline. I added the screenshot to show what happens if I try to delete these files.

Thanks!

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: @SLaks - I understand it. But it is from someone unknown. I am afraid , is it some kind of tracker??

Comment: No; it's just a file that was shared with you.

Comment: @SLaks- I don't want anyone to share any file with me. What can I do to prevent someone from sharing any file with me without my permission?